# Scala Return Type Equal to Argument Type

Tags: scala

I would like to have the functionality described below for a static method (i.e., without F-Bounded Polymorphism), but I haven't been able to so far. I would greatly appreciate your input.

Let's assume we have the following class hierarchy:

```
sealed trait A
case class B(value: Int) extends A
case class C(value: Int) extends A
```

If I try to do the following, the compiler will complain:

```
def doSomething[T <: A](arg1: T, arg2: Any, ...): T = {
  arg1 match {
    case b: B => B(5)
    case c: C => C(5)
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Complain with what error?

Comment: That B(5) and C(5) do not conform with return type T.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, with this class hierarchy there is no way to express it.
2. The only possible implementation without *incorrect in general* casts, or throwing exceptions, for `def doSomething[T <: A](arg1: T, arg2: Any, ...): T` is `def doSomething[T <: A](arg1: T, arg2: Any, ...): T = arg1`. By "incorrect in general" I mean that adding `.asInstanceOf[T]` at the end will make it compile, but there will be programs which shouldn't typecheck and do.
3. F-Bounded polymorphism was invented to solve precisely this problem. Any other solution is going to be equivalent or worse.

Comment: But how can I make this work with F-Bounded polymorphism if I want `doSomething` to be static?

Comment: What do you mean by static? Scala doesn't have static methods.

Comment: I mean belonging to some object rather than a class.

Comment: `trait Ops[T <: Ops[T]] {self: T => def doSomething(arg1: T, ...): T }` and then `object Bops extends Ops[B]` does not do it because we also want `T <: A`